# How to keep linear interpolation setting without uv map bleeding?

Tags: uv, interpolation

[image]So I have a texture atlas with a uv map for tiles in my landscape. I know you can set interpolation as closest to stop the bleeding, but I dont like the look of my textures with closest interpolation on. Is there any way to keep it linear without the bleeding? The bleed is the white lines between each uv tile.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share a screenshot that describes the issue?

Comment: I'm using a uv map to tile textures. but using linear interpolation gives me a white outline round each tile.

Comment: The usual solution is to add padding around the islands in the atlas: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding